# difference of date in sql and php

Tags: php, sql, mysql, sql-server, oracle

how can calculate

```
(now) - (date in database)
```

Comment: What do you want the difference in?  Seconds?  Days?

Answer (score 4):

MySQL:

```
SELECT CURDATE() - t.date
  FROM TABLE t
```

SQL Server:

```
SELECT GETDATE() - t.date
  FROM TABLE t
```

Oracle:

```
SELECT SYSDATE - t.date
  FROM TABLE t
```

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind "now" (for the session) could be in one timezone and the database in a separate in a separate timezone. For Oracle, sysdate will use the database timezone and dates stored in the database without a timezone will be assumed to be in the database timezone.

```
alter session set time_zone='Europe/Zurich';
select sysdate, current_date from dual;
SYSDATE                    CURRENT_DATE
-------------------------- --------------------------
01/Feb/2010 16:08          01/Feb/2010 06:08
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple function where as `$currenttime = the time now`, and `$time = the time in the SQL`.

Just `$product = $currenttime-$time`;

and then `echo $product`